# How do set my radio buttons to only select one option while also validating XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: validation, radio-button, label, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have two radio buttons and I would like only one to be selected at a time. The code that I am using works, but I get a warning from the validator saying:

> **Validation Output: 1 Warning**
>
> Below is a list of the warning message(s) produced when checking your document.
>    Line 115, Column 26: reference to non-existent ID "addressType"
>
> `<td><label for="addressType">Address For</label></td>`
>
> This error can be triggered by:
>
> A non-existent input, select or textarea element
>   A missing id attribute
>   A typographical error in the id attribute
>   Try to check the spelling and case of the id you are referring to.

The code that I am using is:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="addressType">Address For</label></td>
<td><label for="homeType">Home</label>
    <input type="radio" id="homeType" name="addressType" value="home" />
    <label for="busType">Business</label>
    <input type="radio" id="busType" name="addressType" value="business" /></td>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am happy that you solved your problem. Please add your solution as the answer. This will help others who may be facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

As the validation error indicates you should only set `<label>` elements for items which have an id. That id value should then be set into the `for` attribute.